# AWS Amplify/Cognito: How to opt in/out of MFA before first login?

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to configure MFA for users so that:

- MFA is optional
- MFA, if selected, is used on first login

This is the flow that I figured would be the case:

1. Auth.signUp - Register the user - Cognito sends a verification code via e-mail
2. Auth.confirmSignUp - Verify the user's e-mail - This returns a user, which is set locally
3. Auth.setPreferredMfa - Set the preferred mfa type based on user's selection
4. Redirect the user to login
5. User logs in, goes through MFA if it was set, or just logs in if it wasn't

(Ideally Auth.signUp would take preferred mfa so that creating a user with correct mfa settings is transactional but it clearly doesn't, and I digress)

Up to this point, we had mandatory MFA, so we didn't have step 3 and everything was working great.

Now that I set MFA to optional in the user pool, and added step 3, I get an error because the user that is returned from the confirmSignUp is *COMFIRMED* but not *AUTHENTICATED*, and setPreferredMfa requires an authenticated user, meaning that the user has to be logged in so that we can make the setPreferredMfa call. This is the rub.

What I ***can*** do - but don't ***want*** to do - is keep the name/password around so that after step 3, I manually log the user in (Auth.signIn(name, pass)), call Auth.setPreferredMfa, then log the user out, and then redirect them to login for the "first time".

That feels pretty janky, and in the (albeit, unlikely) scenario that there's network instability after Auth.confirmSignUp and before the Auth.signIn->Auth.setPreferredMfa calls, then it'd be broken.

I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going the route of logging the user in after they validated the registration, then calling `setPreferredMfa(...)`.

We opted not to log the user out and let them stay logged in.